# VSTS Licensing and Release Management

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to understand the pricing for Release Management. I understand it is included as part of VSTS. We have Visual Studio Professional Licenses. Does that give us VSTS and Release Management as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Visual Studio Licenses and VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) Release are separate things.**

And VSTS Release is free (for five users per account), so you can create a VSTS account and then manage/build/release your project by VSTS. Detail steps as below:

1. You can create a VSTS account in https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/.
2. [Create a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-team-project) in VSTS and you can select the version control type (Git or TFVC) when creating a team project.
3. Push/checkin your code to your repo ([Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/) or [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/)).
4. Create build and release definition to build and deploy your code.

There has an CI build and CD deploy process in VSTS, you can refer [CI/CD Hello world](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1).